# I'm getting the last value as the maximum and minimum value

Tags: python

Could someone please tell me what is wrong in this code?

```
#Finding the maximum and minimum value for the entered intigers
while True:
    Read_no= raw_input("Kindly enter a number:")
    if Read_no == 'done':
      break

    try:
       read_no = int(Read_no)
    except :
        print"Invalid input"
        continue
    maximum= None
    minimum= None

    if maximum is None or read_no> maximum:
        maximum= read_no  

    if minimum is None or read_no< minimum:
       minimum= read_no

print "Maximum is", maximum
print "Minimum is", minimum
```

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting maximum and minimum in every iteration. Put the lines that set them to `None` before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

In every loop, `maximum` and `minimum` are re-assigned to `None`. To fix the problem, put their initialization before the loop:

```
maximum = None
minimum = None
while True:
    # ...
```